# StandardTitleBar in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

How to change the background color of the [standard title bar](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/StandardTitleBar.html). I have tried using the StandardTitleBar.setBackground(Background b) , but it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

You cant do this in that way. Try to override the setTitle() function in the MainScreen

Answer (score 0):

check this code.

```
public class CustomScreenTitle extends HorizontalFieldManager {
    private Bitmap titleHeaderImg= null;

    public CustomScreenTitle(String title, Resolutions resolutions){

        super(Manager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL | Manager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR | USE_ALL_WIDTH);
        titleHeaderImg = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("header.png");

        Font f = Resolutions.titleFont;
        int headerWidth = f.getAdvance(title);
        Padding p = resolutions.setTitlePadding(headerWidth);

        CustomLabelField titleLabel = new CustomLabelField(title, Field.FIELD_HCENTER, p, Resolutions.titleFont);
        titleLabel.setFontColor(Color.WHITE);
        add(titleLabel);
    }
      public void paint(Graphics graphics)
      {
          graphics.clear();
          if(titleHeaderImg != null)
          graphics.drawBitmap(0, 0, titleHeaderImg.getWidth(), titleHeaderImg.getHeight(), titleHeaderImg, 0, 0);                       
          super.paint(graphics);
      } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following ... It worked for me:

```
HorizontalFieldManager manager = new HorizontalFieldManager(HorizontalFieldManager.USE_ALL_WIDTH);
manager.setBackground(yourBackground);
manager.add(your field);
setTitle(manager);
```